# PHP Javascript Link

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this link:

```
echo"<a href=\"$urlHTML\" onclick="return confirm('Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details')">Delete</a>";
```

It is used to pass a stripped character link to a page, but before doing so a javascript function is employed to get the user to confirm they want to proceed. Basically, on the link above I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN, expecting ',' or ';' in E:\xampp\htdocs\IDB\delete.php on line 411.
```

If anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

this one should worK:

```
echo '<a href="'.$urlHTML.'" onclick="return confirm(\'please confirm\')">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "<a href=\"$urlHTML\" onclick=\"return confirm('Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details')\">Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

escape the " sign

```
echo"<a href=\"$urlHTML\" onclick=\"return confirm('Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details')\">Delete</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

make it like this

```
 echo"<a href=\"$urlHTML\" onclick=\"return confirm('Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details')\">Delete</a>";
```

You have forgot to escape the inner double quotes of onclick.

Answer (score 0):

separate PHP and HTML

```
?>
<a href="<?=$urlHTML?>" onclick="return confirm('Please Confirm You Wish to Add these Details')">Delete</a>
<?php
```